# Slider html5/css display 2 row of images instead one

Tags: css, html

Im trying to insert images in slider. For now only 5 demonstrates in 1 row, but i got 7 and the rest demonstrates in second row. Looks ugly. I know that major changes probably in css , but i have no idea what i need to change.
Thank you for response.

**css:**

```
@keyframes slidy {

0% { left: 0%; }

20% { left: 0%; }

25% { left: -20%; }

45% { left: -30%; }

50% { left: -40%; }

70% { left: -50%; }

75% { left: -80%; }

95% { left: -90%; }

100% { left: -100%; }
}

body, figure { 

 margin: 0; 

font-family: 
"HelveticaNeue-Light",
"Helvetica Neue Light", 
"Helvetica Neue", 
Helvetica, Arial,
 "Lucida Grande", 
sans-serif;

font-weight: 50;

font-size: 15px;

}

div#captioned-gallery { 

 width: 100%; overflow: hidden; 

}

figure.slider { 

  position: relative; width: 300%;

 font-size: 0; animation: 30s slidy infinite; 

}

figure.slider figure { 

 width: 20%; height: auto;

 display: inline-block;  position: inherit; 
}

figure.slider img { width: 20%; height: auto; }

figure.slider figure figcaption { 

 position: absolute; bottom: 0;

 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);

 color: #fff; width: 100%;

font-size: 1rem; padding: .6rem; 
}
```

Image of Resin Toy Cars


 Image of Cat Statuettes

Comment: please do share your HTML codes...

Comment: I cant add. its limit.

Comment: <div id="slider">
    <figure class="slider">
    <figure>

    <img src="European/U1.jpg" alt><figcaption>Image of Resin Toy Cars</figcaption></figure>


    <figure><img src="European/U2.jpg"alt> <figcaption>Image of Cat Statuettes</figcaption></figure>         </figure>
  </div>

Answer (score 0):

Here's one I made earlier ;) You can ignore the transforms that was an effect for another transition. Here is a fiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/o6haapvt/

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.pic-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
figure {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity:0;
    /*animation*/
    animation: slideShow 42s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: slideShow 42s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: slideShow 42s linear infinite 0s;
    -webkit-animation: slideShow 42s linear infinite 0s;
}
.pic-1 {
    animation-delay: 0s;
    -o-animation-delay: 0s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
    background: url(http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/daisies.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
.pic-2 {
    animation-delay: 6s;
    -o-animation-delay: 6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    background: url(http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/snowdrops.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
.pic-3 {
    animation-delay: 12s;
    -o-animation-delay: 12s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
    background: url(http://rachelgallen.com/images/mountains.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
.pic-4 {
    animation-delay: 18s;
    -o-animation-delay: 18s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
    background: url(http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/purpleflowers.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
.pic-5 {
    animation-delay: 24s;
    -o-animation-delay: 24s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
    background: url(http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/yellowflowers.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
.pic-6 {
    animation-delay: 30s;
    -o-animation-delay: 30s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 30s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 30s;
    background: url(http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/daisies.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
.pic-7 {
    animation-delay: 36s;
    -o-animation-delay: 36s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 36s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 36s;
    background: url(http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/snowdrops.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
figure figcaption {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align:center;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding: .6rem;
}
/* keyframes*/
 @keyframes slideShow {
    0% {
        opacity: 0.5;
        transform:scale(1);
        -ms-transform:scale(1);
    }
    4% {
        opacity: 1
    }
    24% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    28% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform:scale(1);
        -ms-transform:scale(1);
    }
}
@-o-keyframes slideShow {
    0% {
        opacity: 0.5;
        -o-transform:scale(1);
    }
    4% {
        opacity: 1
    }
    24% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    28% {
        opacity: 0;
        
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        -o-transform:scale(1);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes slideShow {
    0% {
        opacity: 0.5;
        -moz-transform:scale(1);
    }
    4% {
        opacity: 1
    }
    24% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    28% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform:scale(1.1);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform:scale(1);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideShow {
    0% {
        opacity: .5;
        -webkit-transform:scale(1);
    }
    4% {
        opacity: 1
    }
    24% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    28% {
        opacity: 0;
        
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform:scale(1);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="pic-wrapper">
    <figure class="pic-1">
        <figcaption>Daisies</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure class="pic-2">
        <figcaption>Snowdrops</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure class="pic-3">
        <figcaption>Mountains</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure class="pic-4">
        <figcaption>Purple Flowers</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure class="pic-5">
        <figcaption>Yellow Flowers</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure class="pic-6">
        <figcaption>Daisies Again</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure class="pic-7">
        <figcaption>Snowdrops Again</figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: edit: if you want an effect you can do this http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/gjuL46to/2/